# Microsoft Graph API Get Token 400

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My current technologies: React, Electron, Webpack

This is the link that I am referencing: 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user

So on number 3. Get a Token. I do a post using axios to
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1

with the body

```
{

    client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
    &scope=user.read%20mail.read
    &code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3p
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
    &grant_type=authorization_code
    &client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh
}
```

This is just copied and pasted from their website.  When I do it I use my own client_id, code I get from the previous request and client secret.  However when I make this request, I get a 400.  Can you get a 400 from having non-valid parameter?  Also, I can't have a server running so I put down a fake `localhost:9000` which it errors out, but I am still able to parse the code from that URL.  So is it a problem not having a valid redirect_uri?

Comment: Are you making a POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token or a GET request?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I am making a POST.  And sorry it was a 400 error not 404. Let me change that

Comment: Is there any more content with the 400 error? Usually it returns a message hinting as to what is wrong with your request.

Comment: Also note your redirect uri has to be the same for the auth code request and the token request. You mention you use `localhost:9000` but then in the token request you are using `localhost/myapp/`. These must be the same throughout the request process.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I just copied and pasted the body from their website, but I did happen to have that wrong.  Thanks!  I did find out my problem which was axios does not convert json to x-www-form.  So I had to send it in as a string and that worked!  Thanks for all of your help!